# Applying an XQuery file to an XMl File in C#

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, xquery

I am making a program that takes as input an XML file, XSD schema and an XQuery file.

So far I validate the XML against the XSD.

I now want to apply the XQuery file against the XML file, yet after looking online I can't seem to find any way of doing this in C#.

Would anyone know if this can be done?
It seems there is no inbuilt support for XQuery C#?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

Both [Saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) and [XQSharp](http://www.xqsharp.com/xqsharp/index.htm) are available commercially for .NET. If you want to call into C++, you could also use open source implementations like [XQilla](http://xqilla.sourceforge.net/HomePage) or [Zorba](http://www.zorba-xquery.com/site2/html/).